# UITableView cell height animation

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, animation, today-extension

I do widget. I need to changed cell height with animation. When click "show more" go extra controls.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzjDK.png)

I wrote this code

```
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        showModes(alpha: 1, duration: 0.2, delay: 0.1)
        tableView.endUpdates()

func showModes(alpha: CGFloat, duration: CGFloat, delay: CGFloat) {
    if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) != 0 {
        for i in 0...tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)-1 {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? WidgetCell {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), delay: TimeInterval(delay) ,animations: {
                    if alpha == 0 {
                        cell.favoriteConstraint.constant = -45
                    } else {
                        cell.favoriteConstraint.constant = 10
                    }
                    cell.favoriteMode.alpha = alpha
                    self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
                })

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work smoothly. it dramatically twitches up and down. How do I get this to work smoothly, for example, in the weather widget by Apple?

Answer (score 0):

I can't recognise what is a problem definetly because you posted only part of your code. But I can suggest several checks to do

1. Did you set self-sizing cells for UITableView? AtableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
2. Did you added constraint (favoriteConstraint) to cell's contentView

Also when animating constraint changes you don't need to change it inside animation closure.

The standard code looks like

```
cell.favoriteConstraint.constant = newValue
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
    cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Also you don't need to wrap your method call. This must be ok:

```
showModes(alpha: 1, duration: 0.2, delay: 0.1)
tableView.beginUpdates()    
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Yes, it all added
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ledControllers = readLED()
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

I recorded a video to make it clearer. first cell expands, and only then the animation begins. I wish that it was much like a weather widget
https://youtu.be/f4D7NnoyWrQ

P.S. Судя по нику вы говорите по русски?